# New weed with long root runners - need to identify and eliminate

Tags: weed-control, weeds

I have some weeds growing in the garden, but don't know what it is or how to get rid of it.  Your help is appreciated.

I have an area of shrubs with barck mulch all around.  I noticed these green shoots coming out of the mulch and decided to investigate.  They have roots running under the bark mulch then into the soil underneath.  I have been pulling at the roots, but they generally break and I suspect he roots go down deeper and revive to new runners over time. The runners underneath are sometimes a foot long.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your weed is Field Horsetail (*Equisetum arvense*). To quote from Wikipedia (emphasis is mine):

> It has separate sterile non-reproductive and fertile spore-bearing stems growing from a perennial underground rhizomatous stem system. The fertile stems are produced in early spring and are non-photosynthetic, while the green sterile stems start to grow after the fertile stems have wilted and persist through the summer until the first autumn frosts. Rhizomes can pierce through the soil **up to 6 feet in depth**. This allows this species to tolerate many conditions and is hard to get rid of even with the help of herbicides.

Here are a couple sources that discuss eradication:

- [Chemical and cultural methods](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/kill-horsetail-45689.html)
- [Relatively organic methods](https://www.gardenguides.com/94946-kill-horsetail.html)
- [And a link that refutes the other two](https://laidbackgardener.blog/2015/08/03/how-to-really-control-horsetail/)

Best of luck to you.